# Drupal 6: Heartbeat module is "missing" some content

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, heartbeat

I’m using the heartbeat module on my site to make an activity-stream and recently I discovered that it doesn’t display all the new comments.

I’ve displayed group messaging ‘cause I only want to display @username commented on @node_title and nothing more. But for some reason, when there is several comments submitted within a short range of time it either only displays one of the comments or nothing or it makes an entry in the activity-stream which is just blank.

Before I was using the built-in comment-template in Heartbeat but now I’ve tried to create my own instead. It works when I post a comment but when testing it and makes two comments within e.g. 30 seconds it still makes the error.

Are there any known problems with this issue or am I missing something?? I haven’t detected the problem with adding new nodes, which also can occur within a short period of time on my time.

Thanks
Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 0):

If you are having display failures in Views, there is a patch someone worked out in February 2012 for Views 6.x-3.x - you might want to try that. It fixes the display for a bunch of fields. See http://drupal.org/node/1295570